# Using a C++ DLL with mangled exports

Tags: c++, dll, wrapper

I have been assigned the job of writing a wrapper around an existing C++ code library in the form of a DLL. The problem I'm running unto is that the DLL export names are mangled. Can/should I simply use the mangled names when I pass them into GetProcAddress? or is there a better way to do things?

EDIT: I failed to mention. I do not have access to the code so as to allow me to modify the dll in any way.

EDIT2: It turns out I DO have access to the code (.h and .cpp) for this DLL but I cannot modify said code.

Comment: I suppose you could do a extern { /*methods here*/ } block to avoid mangling

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unless I'm wrong, your solution requires that I edit the DLL code? I cannot, as I do not have access to said code. I also would not be authorized to modify the dll even if I did have code access.

Comment: What kind of wrapper? Do you have access to the headers for the library?

Comment: Technically I'm writing a Java wrapper around the DLL. And no I only have access to the DLL itself. (Unless there's more that I don't fully understand about how DLLs work.)
Edit: in the context of this problem though, I don't think the java aspect of what I'm doing is important. At present I'm simply writing the C++ code that JNI talks to.

Comment: Then why don't you mention java in your question ?

Comment: Do you know with which compiler(version/option) the dll has been compiled ? Do you have the (public) header on the dll ?

Comment: @NeelBasu As I said in my previous comment, The context of this question only applies to writing c++ code to access a c++ DLL. Anything beyond that I already have figured out. 

@ Jarod42 I don't know any information about the compiler it was built on. However, It turns out I DO have access to the code (.h and .cpp) for this DLL but I cannot modify said code.

Comment: So you may create a new DLL with this (unmodifiable DLL) code + your wrapping code...

Comment: That is what I'm going for. A new DLL (as used by JNI) that has functions which call the functions from the old (unmodifiable) DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ultimately settled on for the specific question I asked was the following function. It worked in my case as the export names were only slightly mangled.

```
static FARPROC getFunctionPointer(HINSTANCE dll, const char *baseName)
{
    char buf[256];
    FARPROC fp;
    sprintf(buf,"%s",baseName);
    fp = GetProcAddress(dll,buf);
    if (fp == 0)
    {
      sprintf(buf,"_%s",baseName);
      fp = GetProcAddress(dll,buf);
    }
    if (fp == 0)
    {
      sprintf(buf,"_%s@4",baseName);
      fp = GetProcAddress(dll,buf);
    }
    if (fp == 0)
    {
      sprintf(buf,"_%s@8",baseName);
      fp = GetProcAddress(dll,buf);
    }
    if (fp == 0)
    {
      sprintf(buf,"_%s@0",baseName);
      fp = GetProcAddress(dll,buf);
    }

    if (fp == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Could not locate function: %s \n", baseName);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

Comment: That's not name mangling, it is __stdcall name decoration.  You get it from the .h file, it is *not* arbitrary.  If you don't know the calling convention or how many arguments the function takes then you have no hope of calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the source code (unmodifiable).

Create a project with DLL source code files.
Create wrapper.cpp/wrapper.h with

// wrapper.h

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

extern "C" {

    void wrapper_function1();
    // and so on
}
#endif
```

// wrapper.cpp

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "dll.h"

extern "C" {
    void wrapper_function1() { /* code which may call functions from dll.h */ }
    // And so on
}
```

And so your new DLL has no name mangling.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. However, this does not answer the question. (It also turns out this solution will not work according to those who wrote the cpp code in the first place.)  My question is how to call an export with a mangled name. Not how to find an alternate solution.

Comment: So you can still use mangled names, but you may have problem when DLL will be recompiled by other compiler/version...